# The reading of 町 for different towns

Tags: kanji, readings

The following is an excerpt from an article on NHK News Web Easy.
[image]

Why is one town called Takamori-**machi** but the other one -  Yamato-**chou**? The kanji for “town” is the same but the reading is different for the different towns…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally it is not possible to predict whether 町 is read as まち or ちょう.

大手町 at the center of Tokyo is read as おおてまち while there is [大手町]{おおてちょう} in Kishiwada city of Osaka ([source](https://style.nikkei.com/article/DGXNASFK01024_R01C11A1000000/)).

As mentioned in the link, ちょう is more common in Western Japan whereas まち is dominant in Eastern Japan.